# Validation in ViewModel and DB schema

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, ef-code-first, dry

For now I'm using a validation in ViewModels and in POCO-models. Validation in POCO-model I do for correct DB schema. But in this approach I duplicate same code (eg. - Required for both models). It's not the DRY principle. How avoid duplication?